# How to switch from web.xml based authorization to authorization via annotations in a JAX-RS application

Tags: java, jboss, authorization, security, resteasy

I have a working (web.xml based) container authentication and authorization. Due to the limitation of `<url-pattern>` I need to `switch to javax.annotation.security` annotations. I found out that I need a additional configuration in my web.xml in order to turn on the role based security annotations. [Described in the RESTEasy UserGuide](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy)

But that doesn't work for me: I get an error 404 (Could not find resource for relative : /services/customers/1) depending on whether

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

are defined in the web.xml or not right after the `<context-param>` and `<listener>`

This is my old (existing) *web.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Store_Service</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>SSL Secured WebService</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authenticated customers only</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/customers/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>CUST</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Authentication-REALM</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>CUST</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Which configuration items are still needed and which one need to be added in order to make `@RolesAllowed("CUST")` working.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your web.xml needs the following:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If everything fails, you could try to use the standard way, using SecurityContext:

```
@Context SecurityContext myContext;

@GET
@javax.ws.rs.Produces("text/html")
public Response doGet() {
  if(myContext.isUserInRole("CUST") == false) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The param-name you suggested also didn't worked for me, and right now I rechecked it again, unfortunately no success. And you are right, the approach with the SecurityContext is a possibility too. But it would be nice if I can do this with the security annotations. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add this to the web.xml: `<listener><listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class></listener>`

Comment: Still no success, I tried it in combination with `<servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>`, then I got an error 404. An without the listener for the `HttpServletDispatcher` I can still access the resource without any authentication. (The `<context-param>` entry was present too)

Comment: Well, when you get 401 (Unauthorized), you are in the right track. This means you are not authenticated (like, forgot to enter the password), or your realm configuration is broken, and of course, this is not your role. I suggest you make a test method, using `SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal()` to confirm that your realm/role/user configuration is not broken.

Comment: Now I tried to change the configuration in all its variations, still no luck. You are right, I mentioned in the question, that I got an error 401, which would mean that the security annotation is working as expected. Unforunately I couldn't reproduce this behaviour again, so I'm pretty sure that this was a mistake by me while writing the question, hence I updated it accordingly. The results for the last hour were that either I can access the protected resources without authentication or I got an error 404

Comment: Another try: Keep the `resteasy.role.based.security` context-param and change your constraints to `<auth-constraint><role-name>*</role-name></auth-constraint>`, even for the security-constraints that does not have one.

Comment: I added: `<auth-constraint>
   <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>` for the `<url-pattern>/services/customers/*</url-pattern>` which causes the basic login form to be displayed. The customer resource methods are annotated with `@RolesAllowed("CUST")` but now it doesn't matter to wich role the logged in user is assigned, access is granted in all cases as long the user belongs to any role.

Comment: The reason to use `*` in `web.xml`, was to let the user proceed free in the WebContainer validation, then on the method level, the Servlet would validate the role. If your code and configuration is correct, org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor will be called, and will execute this line `if (context.isUserInRole(role)) return null;`. From your last test, can you confirm that the `<security-roles>` for "CUST" was inside the web.xml?

Comment: Yes, that part of the configuration wasn't changed. The config item: `<security-role>
        <role-name>CUST</role-name>
    </security-role>` was still there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about RESTEasy but if you want to do the same in RESTful here you have below link which might give your answer. That you need to register your security filter with resource config and then add this resource config in web.xml file.

http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-security/

Comment: This worked for me. By the way this is very useful when you want to modify default behavior of the annotations.